# Access parent for loop scope in child template in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

#### parent.txt

```
{% for dict in list_of_dictionaries %}
    {% block pick_dictionary_element %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endfor %}
```

#### child_one.txt

```
{% extends "parent.txt" %}
{% block pick_dictionary_element %}
    {{ dict.a }}
{% endblock %}
```

#### child_two.txt

```
{% extends "parent.txt" %}
{% block pick_dictionary_element %}
    {{ dict.b }}
{% endblock %}
```

Then:

```
from jinja2 import Template, Environment, FileSystemLoader
e = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader("./"))
e.get_template("child_one.txt").render(list_of_dictionaries=[{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}])
```

produces an empty output. How can I access the `dict` var from the parent for loop? I kind of imagined jinja just in-lining the `pick_dictionary_element` and the child having the for loop scope of its parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to what you are trying to do is to use the [`scoped`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#block-nesting-and-scope) keyword on your block:

```
{# parent.txt #}
{% for dict in list_of_dictionaries %}
    {% block pick_dictionary_element scoped %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endfor %}
```

#### Why was this hard to debug?

You made the mistake of using the name `dict` in the loop:

```
{% for dict in list_of_dictionaries %}
```

The side effect of this was that the child template did not readily complain, since the symbol `dict` exists in its context.  If instead, you had done something like:

```
{# parent.txt #}
{% for a_dict in list_of_dictionaries %}
    {% block pick_dictionary_element %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endfor %}

{# child_one.txt #}
{% extends "parent.txt" %}
{% block pick_dictionary_element %}
    {{ a_dict.a }}
{% endblock %}
```

You would have been told:

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'a_dict' is undefined

Answer (score 1):

> Starting with Jinja 2.2, you can explicitly specify that variables are available in a block by setting the block to “scoped” by adding the scoped modifier to a block declaration

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#block-nesting-and-scope

```
{# parent.txt #}
{% for dict in list_of_dictionaries %}
    {% block pick_dictionary_element scoped %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endfor %}
```